# Inconveniente con instanciamiento de una clase en Java

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee

Tengo dentro de un paquete con nombre Interfaces un archivo con nombre Clientes.java, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
package Interfaces;

import java.util.List;

//Modelo.Clientes; Ojo en el video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3HER9EGQSI&list=PLkaQhEBG4ck1T6ORjHpS3o5oq-DeZnFSz&index=5 (Como Hacer CRUD en JAVA JSP con Patron MVC y MYSQL - Parte 01) en 6:11 importaron import Modelo.Clientes; aqui no me lo acepta 

public interface Clientes {
    public List listarclie();
    public Clientes list(String nit);
    public boolean add(Clientes cli);
    public boolean edit(Clientes cli);
    public boolean eliminar(String nit); 
   
    public List buscar(String texto); 
    
}
```

Estoy realizando mi requerimiento de acuerdo a lo que se explica en el momento 7:49 del siguiente videotutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3HER9EGQSI, en el que se instancia una clase mediante lo siguiente:

```
public class ClientesDAO implements Clientes {
    Conexion cn=new Conexion();  
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Clientes c = new Clientes();   // Aquí se me presenta el inconveniente debido a que en Clientes();
```

El error que me muestra dice:

> Clientes is abstract , cannot be instantiated

No se por que me muestra error pues en video que socializo no aparece error.

Muchas gracias anticipadas por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Clientes es una interfaz? eso es correcto?

Comment: La clase Cliente está en el paquete Modelo. Lo puedes ver tu mismo en el minuto 5:00. Aunque si fuera tu buscaría un vídeos mejores.

Comment: He estado viendo el tutorial un poco por encima y, aunque se explica decentemente, no sigue las convenciones de Java. Un paquete siempre tiene su nombre en minúsculas, por ejemplo. Y escribir código Java en un JSP... hace ya 15 años que eso se considera una mala práctica

Comment: Si señor Cliente es una interfaz

Answer (score 1):

Estás confundiendo los componentes al tratar de reintepretar el ejemplo para tu propio caso (y no está mal, pero es importante que entiendas qué pasa)

En el minuto 5 muestran cómo la clase Persona se crea con atributos de una persona, getter y setters. Es algo que puede asimilarse a un DTO, una clase para transferir unos datos estructurados de un lugar a otro. Los datos de una persona. Es una POJO, una clase Java común y corriente.

LUEGO, crean una interfaz CRUD que define métodos para crear, editar, consultar y eliminar elementos de cualquier tipo. Es un prototipo de DAO.

Después hacen lo que intentas, que es implementar el DAO, las operaciones para acceder a elementos Persona (PersonaDAO). Así pues, PersonaDAO implementa EL CRUD, no a la Persona, que es otro patrón.

En tu caso, ClientesDAO no debe implementar Cliente (PD. no uses nombres en plural, pues una instancia de CLiente sólo representa UN cliente). Y te sigue faltando la interfaz CRUD si es que quieres seguir el ejemplo. Y, efectivamente, uno no puede instanciar una interfaz así sin más; uno instancia la clase que la implementa (PersonaDAO en el video).

Puedes revisar cuál es el diseño en tu implementación particular y revisar cuál es la interfaz y cuál es el DTO, para que puedas seguir el ejercicio. Lo otro es que no es un tutorial muy reciente, así que bien podrías buscar ejemplos más recientes y que sean más estrictos con las buenas prácticas en nomenclatura.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes tener muy claro lo que es una interface.

Hago referencia a la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html):

> **Interfaces en Java**
>
> En el lenguaje de programación Java, una interfaz es un tipo de referencia, similar a una clase, que solo puede contener constantes, firmas de métodos, métodos predeterminados, métodos estáticos y tipos anidados. Los cuerpos de método existen solo para métodos predeterminados y métodos estáticos. ***No se pueden crear instancias de interfaces; solo se pueden implementar mediante clases o ampliar mediante otras interfaces***. La extensión se analiza más adelante en esta lección.

Como vez una *Interface* no puede ser instanciada cosa que realizas en la línea:

```
Clientes c = new Clientes();
```

En todo caso ésta debería ser implementada en una clase entonces podrás instanciar y utilizar esta como bien realizas con la clase *ClientesDAO*.